# JNI with RMI not working

Tags: java, java-native-interface, rmi

I am trying to use a native c++ function with JNI and want to make it available over RMI.

When connecting the RMI client to the RMI server and accessing the method containing the native function, I get following error message:

```
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: rmi.Server.setInputOutputPaths(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.setInputAndOutputPaths(Unknown Source)
at rmi.RMIClient.setInputAndOutputPaths(RMIClient.java:47)
at rmi.RMIClient.main(RMIClient.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: rmi.Server.setInputOutputPaths(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at rmi.Server.setInputOutputPaths(Native Method)
at rmi.Server.setInputAndOutputPaths(Server.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: rmi.Server.createNN([ID)V
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createNeuralNetwork(Unknown Source)
at rmi.RMIClient.createNeuralNetwork(RMIClient.java:55)
at rmi.RMIClient.main(RMIClient.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: rmi.Server.createNN([ID)V
at rmi.Server.createNN(Native Method)
at rmi.Server.createNeuralNetwork(Server.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Server Interface:

```
package rmi;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ServerInterface extends Remote
{
    public void setInputAndOutputPaths(String inputPath, String outputPath) throws RemoteException;
    public void createNeuralNetwork(int[] topology, double learnRate) throws RemoteException;
    public void trainNeuralNetwork(String inputDataFileName, int numIterations) throws RemoteException;
    public void tradeUsingNeuralNetwork(String inputDataFileName) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Server Code:

```
package rmi;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

import rmi.ServerInterface;

public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface
{
    Server() throws RemoteException
    {
        super();
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("BAITLibrary");
    }

    public native void setInputOutputPaths(char[] inputPath, char[] outputPath);
    public native void createNN(int[] topology, double learnRate);
    public native void trainNN(String inputDataFileName, int numIterations);
    public native void trade(String inputDataFileName);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);

            ServerInterface engine = new Server();
            //ServerInterface stub = (ServerInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);

            registry.rebind("Server", engine);
        }

        catch (RemoteException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setInputAndOutputPaths(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
        try {
            new Server().setInputOutputPaths(inputPath, outputPath);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createNeuralNetwork(int[] topology, double learnRate) {
        try {
            new Server().createNN(topology, learnRate);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void trainNeuralNetwork(String inputDataFileName, int numIterations) {
        try {
            new Server().trainNN(inputDataFileName, numIterations);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void tradeUsingNeuralNetwork(String inputDataFileName) {
        try {
            new Server().trade(inputDataFileName);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
package rmi;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;


import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;


public class RMIClient {
    private ServerInterface server;

    public RMIClient() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RMIClient huan = new RMIClient();
        huan.connect();

        String inputPath = "C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\Huan\\Input\\NN_1";
        String outputPath = "C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\Huan\\Output\\NN_1";
        int[] topology = { 25, 35, 50, 15, 1 };
        double learnRate = 0.009;

        huan.setInputAndOutputPaths(inputPath, outputPath);
        huan.createNeuralNetwork(topology, learnRate);
    }

    public void connect() {

        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
            server = (ServerInterface) registry.lookup("Server");

            //server = (ServerInterface)Naming.lookup("Server");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setInputAndOutputPaths(String inputPath, String outputPath) {
        try {
            server.setInputAndOutputPaths(inputPath, outputPath);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createNeuralNetwork(int[] topology, double learnRate) {
        try {
            server.createNeuralNetwork(topology, learnRate);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void trainNeuralNetwork(String inputDataFileName, int numIterations) {
        try {
            server.trainNeuralNetwork(inputDataFileName, numIterations);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void tradeUsingNeuralNetwork(String inputDataFileName) {
        try {
            server.tradeUsingNeuralNetwork(inputDataFileName);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The server is started with: "-Djava.library.path=C:/Users/Fabian/Desktop/BAITLibrary/x64/Debug" to add the .dll file to the java path.

Comment: The code resulting from your edits does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

The error says you are trying to call a method that takes two `String` arrays:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
    rmi.Server.setInputOutputPaths(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

However, in the interface (and the implementation), the method takes two `char` arrays:

```
public void setInputAndOutputPaths(char[] inputPath, char[] outputPath)
                throws RemoteException;
```

Either change the interface and implementation to take two `char` arrays, or make sure you pass `char` arrays instead of `String` arrays on the calling side.

Are you sure your client code is up-to-date, or are you using an older version on the client side?

Comment: Exactly. Moral of the story: generating the .h file from `javap` is part of the build process, and checking the .c file after changing the .h file is part of the programmer's job.

Comment: I tried it with Strings and I got the same error message. The char[] was just used to try out if it worked that way.

Comment: @ottoman You changed the interface. You didn't (a) change the implementation, (b) recompile the implementation, (c) rebuild the .h file, (d) make sure the .c file agrees with it, (e) recompile the .c file, or (f) relink the shared library.

Comment: I meant that I was originally using Strings. I then changed String to char[] and forgot to revert the change before putting the question online.

Comment: @ottoman Sigh. Suppose you post the real code that you are really running that really causes this priblem. At present it is just an unintelligible mess.